# Как сделать такую формулу круга?

Tags: php, тригонометрия

Помогите пожалуйста решить данный вопрос! Хочу сделать такой круг. Каждый енити (предмет) - это объект.

Есть вот такие начальные данные:

```
<?php
 $count_entities = 8; // кол-во объектов (ентити)
 $radius = 2; // радиус круга
 $center = ['x'=>0, 'y'=>0, 'z'=>0]; // центр круга
```

Нужно сначала такой круг сделать, а после нужно формула, чтобы крутить этот круг, нужно что-то отнимать

Скриншот того, что хочу получить:
[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
function drawEntity(x, y) {
  // Отрисовка. Координаты x и y относительны центра окружности
}

$delta = 2 * pi() / $count
for ($i = 0; $i < 2 * pi(); $i += $delta) {
  drawEntity(sin($i) * $radius, cos($i) * $radius);
}
```

Comment: А можете пожалуйста помочь с вопросом, как его крутить? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1434768/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3