# Как крутить данный круг?

Tags: php, тригонометрия

Помогите пожалуйста с кодом, как крутить данный круг? Пытаюсь его крутить, но они все смещаются в один. То есть, был круг, а потом все эти предметы вставли в кучу.

Создал вот такой круг:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

За этот круг отвечает такой код:

```
$delta = 2 * pi() / 7;
   for ($i=0; $i < 2 * pi(); $i += $delta) { 
     $this->drawEntity(
        new Vector3(
          $player->getX() + sin($i) * 1,
          $player->getY() + cos($i) * 1,
          $player->getZ()
     ), $player);
   }

 public function drawEntity($pos, $player) {
        $pk = new AddEntityPacket;
        $pk->entityRuntimeId = Entity::$entityCount++;
        $pk->type = 68;
        $pk->x = $pos->getX();
        $pk->y = $pos->getY();
        $pk->z = $pos->getZ();
        $pk->yaw = 0;
        $pk->pitch = 0;
        $pk->metadata = [];
        $player->dataPacket($pk);

        $this->getServer()->getScheduler()->scheduleRepeatingTask(
            new Rotate($this, $player, $pk->entityRuntimeId, $player->asVector3()), 1
        );
    }
```

Вот так пытаюсь его крутить, но не получается:

```
class Rotate extends PluginTask
{
    public function __construct($plugin, $player, $eid, $center) {
        parent::__construct($plugin);
        $this->player = $player;
        $this->eid = $eid;
        $this->center = $center;
        $this->delta = 0;
    }

    public function onRun($currentTick)
    {
        $this->delta += 2 * pi() / 7 * 1;
        $cos = cos($this->delta);
        $sin = sin($this->delta);

        $pk = new \pocketmine\network\mcpe\protocol\MoveEntityPacket();
        $pk->entityRuntimeId = $this->eid;
        $pk->x = $this->center->getX() + $cos * 1;
        $pk->y = $this->center->getY() + $sin * 1;
        $pk->z = $this->center->getZ();
        $pk->yaw = 0;
        $pk->pitch = 0;
        $pk->headYaw = 0;
        $this->player->dataPacket($pk);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 3):

### Как рисуется окружность

Возьмем некий счетчик `$i` - он будет означать в каком месте на окружности мы находимся

[image: Значения $i]

На картинке вы можете увидеть какое значение `$i` соответствует позиции на окружности

Теперь встает вопрос:

> Как мне из этого `$i` получить координаты?

`$x = sin($i) * $radius`

`$y = cos($i) * $radius`

*синуc и косинус возвращают значения в диапазоне [-1; 1], потому умножаем на радиус*

Таким образом если в цикле к `$i` прибавлять `pi / 2`, мы получим 4 точки

Найти 'размер' шага можно так: `$delta = $pi * 2 / $countOfPoints`

### Как 'крутить' круг

Чтобы отрисовать окружность 'под углом', достаточно просто начать рисовать её не с нуля, а, например, с `pi / 2`. Таким образом мы повернем окружность на 90° по часовой стрелке.

### Код

```
function drawEntity($entity, $x, $y) {
  // Отрисовка. Координаты x и y относительны центра окружности
}

// $startRadian - это и есть та самая переменная, которая отвечает за вращение
function drawCircleOfEntities($startRadian, $entities, $radius) {
  $delta = 2 * pi() / count($entities); // находим шаг
  $stepNum = 0;
  for ($i = $startRadian; $i <= 2 * pi() + $startRadian; $i += $delta) {
    drawEntity($entities[$stepNum], sin($i) * $radius, cos($i) * $radius);
    $stepNum++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Если ответ решает вашу задачу, пожалуйста, отметьте его галочкой.
Если ответ вам ещё и понравился, нажмите на стрелочку вверх)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а что за startRadian? Что в ней нужно указывать?)

Comment: и что в $entities?)

Comment: $startRadian Это угол поворота в радианах. Если вам нужен угол в градусах: (кол-во градусов)° × π/180

Comment: $entities - массив элементов которые должны рисоваться "кругом". Вы можете и отойти от массива и передавать только кол-во элементов. Но как по мне такой подход не очень то и хорош

Comment: на счёт radian не понял)))

Comment: Сомневаюсь что я смогу хорошо объяснить насчет радианов. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Радиан